# What do metrics actually measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, definition, intuition

To my understanding, the idea of metrics is to measure the quantity of substance in reality. For example:

1. For the metric "meter", if objects $A,B$ are 2 meter apart, objects $C,D$ are 1 meter apart, then this means there are more substance (e.g. air) between $A,B$ than between $C,D$.
2. For the metric "square meter", if land $A$ has area 1 square meter, land $B$ has area 2 square meters, then this means land $A$ covers more substance (e.g. soil) than land $B$ does.
3. For the metric "cubic meter", if tank $A$ has 1 cubic meter water, tank $B$ has 2 cubic meters, then this means $A$ contains more water molecules than $B$.

But from the mathematical understanding of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that seems to be another different story. Along with the concept of *cardinality* in mathematics, sets $A$ and $B$ has the same cardinality if there is a bijection $f:A\rightarrow B$. Using this idea, it is easy to see that

- The interval $[0,1]$ and the interval $[0,2]$ have the same cardinality by the map $f(x)=2x$.
- The unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and the square $[0,2]\times[0,2]$ have the same cardinality by the map $f(x,y)=(2x,2y)$.

Similarly, we can generate these examples to vector spaces of any dimension.

The main differece between reality and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is reality has finite substance (at least in a bounded area) while $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains infinitely many points in any bounded area. My explanation to this is that we are viewing the reality as a simulation of the framework of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by mean of saying each $k$ points on a straight line represents one unit of length in $\mathbb{R}$. Then

- a unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ could mean a land that covers $k^2$ points;
- a unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ could mean a tank that contains $k^3$ point...

which resolves the above-mentioned problem.

However, it also yields another problem. Let us consider the concept of *perimeter*. If a square has side length $a$, then we say its perimeter is $4a$. The idea of this definition was initially to measure the quantity of points that surrounds the square. If we view every one unit of length be represented by $k$ points and assume $a$ is an integer, then each side of the square consists of $ka$ points (with the endpoints overlapped by another side), and so the total number of points that surround the square is $4ka-4$, meaning the precise "perimeter" should be $4a-4/k$. Of course, we may increase the "$k$" so that the precise "perimeter" gets arbitrarily close to the defined one. But $k$ is a finite number after all, so a gap always exist.

Does this mean the original "perimeter" (or "circumference") are not good definitions? Or was it a problem of metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Or there is some inconsistency of the concept of "cardinality" and the reality (since our world is always finite if we look locally)?

Answer (score 3):

No, "cardinality" is not inconsistent with "perimeter".

Instead, the modern concept of perimeter incorporates, in addition to cardinality, further tools of analysis such as infimums, supremums, and limits. See for example the [definition of the length of a rectifiable curve](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Rectifiable_curve), which is how perimeter is defined rigorously.

In addition, I don't think there was ever an "original" definition of perimeter that matches exactly what you wrote in your question. Instead, the earliest perimeter calculations done by ancient Greek mathematicians such as Archimedes already use limit concepts, in addition to the kinds of counting concepts in your question. Much of the history of geometry since then has been an increasing understanding and formalization of the use of limit concepts.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you’re attempting to call “metric” is actually “measure” (I presume the confusion is due to the use of the term metric in “metric units”). In mathematics, we use “metric” for a closely related concept—to capture the essential properties of “distance”.

To summarily resolve your problem, I’d say that there’s no inconsistency in the concept of cardinality (except for what we would call “counterintuitive” results) and the traditional definitions of perimeter/length, area, and volume are all “good” and well-defined. Roughly speaking, you can think of “measure” (or what you refer to as “metric”) as the “size” of a set and cardinality as “number” of elements in the set; however, what’s important, and advisable, is to know these by their formal definitions and experience them through examples.

I would suggest the entry (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) for an introduction to Measure Theory.